# accessing vars inside a js function

Tags: javascript

So I have a pseudo class with functions and vars inside of it. For example:

```
function MyClass()
{
    this.a = 0;
    this.b = function(c)
    {
        this.a += c;
    }
}
```

Then, when I go to use it later I'll do this:

```
var myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.b(3);
myObject.b(5);
```

but when I do this:

```
console.log("A: " + myObject.a);
```

I get:

```
A: 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my actual code. It's split into mutiple files but I'll put up the ones that are relevant:

```
function SongDatabase() {

    this.songs = new Array();

    this.loadSongs = function () {

    };

    this.saveSongs = function () {

    };

    var _Constructor_ = function () {
            var mySong = new Song();
            this.songs = new Array(mySong);
        };
    _Constructor_();
}

function LyriX() {
    var songDatabase = new SongDatabase();
    //var playlistDatabase = new PlaylistDatabase();
    songDatabase.loadSongs();
    var sourceList = new ScrollableList();
    sourceList.setElement($S.getElement("sourceList"));
    var accessoryList = new ScrollableList();
    accessoryList.setElement($S.getElement("accessoryList"));

    var sourceListClick = function (index) {
            $S.log("source click: " + index);
            if (index == 0) {
                displaySongs();
            }
        };
    sourceList.setClickListener(sourceListClick);

    var displaySongs = function () {
            $S.log("display songs");
            // STACK OVERFLOW LOOK HERE!!! thanks :)
            // in debug in chrome songDatabase.songs is a zero length array
            accessoryList.loadArray(songDatabase.songs);
        };
}

$S.addOnLoadListener(function () {
    new LyriX();
});
```

Comment: I get 8, not 0, http://jsfiddle.net/FRGEr/

Comment: Then your code is correct. :)  Maybe you should post the actual code that is giving you trouble.

Comment: @vbman11 - So what in your code is different to Ray's jsfiddle?

Comment: just added a chunk of my real code :)

Comment: btw $S is my personal js library, log just outputs to the console, getElement is just document.getElementById

Comment: and "Song" is another personal class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see someone's taking the "Java" in JavaScript too literally. :)

A couple things you should know about JavaScript:

1. In JavaScript, arrays don't work like they do in other languages.
   They're a lot more like dictionaries then what you would call an array in C or Java;
   they're not significantly more memory efficient, or faster;
   no preallocation is done;
   there's no offeset, etc, in the low-level implementation.
   JavaScript arrays are little more than a convenient (but useful!) structure
   for holding order-imperative data.
2. Arrays can be created using the `new Array(length)` expression, 
   or the simple literal expression, `[]`.
   Generally, you'll want to use the array literal, `[]`.
3. Using `new Array(length)` doesn't really do anything useful; 
   it sets the initial `length` property of the array, but that's basically it.
   All elements remain `undefined`. 
   There are no additional constraints or bounds checking.
   You can do `a[100] = 'whatever'` on an array created by calling `var a = new Array(5)`
   and the interpreter won't bat an eye.
4. JavaScript uses prototypal inheritance which is significantly different then the 
   classical inheritance model used in languages like C++ and Java.

With these points in mind, lets examine the following code block:

```
function SongDatabase() {
    this.songs = new Array();
    this.loadSongs = function () {
        // etc.
    };

    this.saveSongs = function () {
        // etc.
    };

    var _Constructor_ = function () {
        var mySong = new Song();
        this.songs = new Array(mySong);
    };
    _Constructor_();
}
```

This block of code is probably not doing what you think it's doing.

1. By initializing the `SongDatabase` methods inside the `SongDatabase()` function 
   you're creating new method functions for every instance of `songDatabase`.
   This may not be a big deal when you're dealing with a couple of dozen of instances, 
   but if you're dealing with *hundreds*, the extra memory required can become a problem.
   You'll want to use the `prototype` pattern here, instead (see below).
2. Your `_Constructor_` function isn't doing anything. 
   `var mySong = new Song()` creates a new `mySong` object 
   local to the `_Constructor_` function and *not accessible outside of it*. 
   When the `_Constructor_` invocation returns, 
   it's `mySong` variable is garbage collected (like any other local variable would be).
3. `_Constructor_` is a private function and **not a method**;
   I'm not entirely sure what `this` in that context will reference. 
   You may end up creating a songs property on the global object 
   (but I'd want to test that to be sure).
4. As I mentioned earlier, when you call `Array()` with the `new` operator,
   it takes an optional argument that sets the initial `length` of the array. 
   In this case, the interpreter will try to coerce `mySong` into a number 
   (`mySong` is **not** added to the array!); 
   when that fails it will simply return a new array with `length = 0`.

Instead, you're better off writing `SongDatabase()` like so:

```
function SongDatabase() {
    this.songs = [];
    // etc.
}

SongDatabase.prototype.loadSongs = function () {
    // load songs into `this.songs`
};

SongDatabase.prototype.saveSongs = function () {
    // save songs loaded into `this.songs`
};
```

The prototypal pattern may look strange, 
but its probably the best way to handle your use case.
You'll still have direct access to then `songs` array (which may or may not be important), 
and by attaching the `loadSongs` and `saveSongs` functions to `SongDatabase`'s prototype
you ensure that those functions are shared.

Comment: Note that given `var a = new Array(length)`, *a* has no members. `a[0]` returns `undefined` because there is no `a[0]` or any other member, regardless of the value of length. Probably also worth noting that the "order" in an array is only achieved by accessing the properties in sequence, `for..in` iteration will not (and does not in some broswers) necessarily returned the members in any particular order or even a consistent order.

Answer (score 2):

One issue:

```
> var _Constructor_ = function () {
>    var mySong = new Song();
>    this.songs = new Array(mySong);
> };
> _Constructor_();
```

In the above, when `_Constructor_` is called as a function, you don't set its `this` value so it defaults to the global object (in non-strict mode, or undefined in strict mode). So `songs` becomes a global variable or throws an error in strict mode.

It seems like fairly useless function anyway, consider:

```
this.songs = [ new mySong() ];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function MyClass()
{
    this.a = 0;
    this.b = function(c)
    {
        this.a += c;
    }
}
```

change `a+=c` into `this.a+=c;`

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not bound to "classes", as in other languages. Think of it as an object with properties. A single `a` just references a variable "a" (not declared with `var` in the function, so even global in here). You want to update the *property* "a" of the `this` object, use `this.a` instead (the [dot operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) to access the property). You also may want to read [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

---

After your edit (you say you'd been using `this.a`), it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/WKuZe/

---

After you provided us your real code, I noticed this odd structure:

```
function SongDatabase() {
    this.songs = new Array();
    // some methods
    var _Constructor_ = function () {
        var mySong = new Song();
        this.songs = new Array(mySong);
    };
    _Constructor_();
}
```

A constructor like `SongDatabase` is (with the `new` keyword) called with the new instance as `this`. A normal function is usually called on nothing, i.e. `this` is `undefined` or the global object in non-strict mode. See [documentation for the `this` keyword on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

In here, you first initialisize the songDatabases' `songs` property with an empty array. Then, in the `_Constructor_` function, you create an other array with one song but assign it to `window.songs`, because the function is not [called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) on the songDatabase instance. The same problems may occur in your `loadSongs()` method. Apart from calling and [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the usual method to provide a "static" reference to the instance object is a scoped variable:

```
function SongDatabase() {
    var that = this; // <== always points to the instance
    // some methods
    function _Constructor_ () {
        var mySong = new Song();
        that.songs = new Array(mySong);
    //  ^^^^
    };
    _Constructor_();
}
```

If your `_Constructor_` is not a local function, but maybe a interface-adding global function, you might provide the instance (`this`) as an argument or use `_Constructor_.call(this)`, which allows the use of the `this` keyword as if `_Constructor_` were a "class".

Comment: sorry I fixed my post thats how I'm using it in my actual code